# Hide the flag count if I've already handled them all

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, top-bar

Since Aviation is in beta, I got access to the 10k tools at 2k. I've already handled the one flag, but the `[1]` persists on every page I browse to, hereafter.

Can the flag count be updated to only show the number of flags I haven't handled? (i.e. remove it at 0)

[image]

---

[image]